# ¿Cómo evitar que una aplicación se ejecute varias veces?

Tags: c#

Desearía saber cómo poder evitar que cuando se ejecute mi aplicación desktop se pueda volver a ejecutar, es decir, tener 2 instancias corriendo de mi aplicación.

Gracias!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Mediante Mutex es otra opción

```
bool nuevaInstancia;
using (Mutex mutex = new Mutex(true, Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName, out nuevaInstancia ))
{
   if (nuevaInstancia )
   {
     Application.EnableVisualStyles();
     Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
     Application.Run(new MainForm());
  }
}
```

Podrías también en caso de que ya este en ejecución mostrar la ventana de la instancia actual por medio de `SetForegroundWindow` del `user32.dll`

Comment: No necesitas inicializar nuevaIntancia en `true` ya que el valor igual será reemplazado, ni almacenar el nuevo `Mutex` en una variable ya que nunca lo utilizas. Por lo demás esta perfecto

Comment: Incluso si usas C# 7 ni siquiera necesitas declarar `nuevaInstancia` en una línea anterior sino simplemenete así: `new Mutex(true, Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName, out bool nuevaInstancia)`

Comment: Si esa opción de las out varibles son un aporte vastante agradable al lenguaje,  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7

Comment: Muchas gracias!! tu respuesta me ayudó mucho, pude resolverlo así, gracias!

Answer (score 3):

Otro ejemplo con Mutex usando el GUID:

```
    static Mutex mutex = null;

    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {            
        System.Reflection.Assembly assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        Console.WriteLine(assembly.GetType().GUID.ToString());            
        mutex = new Mutex(true,assembly.GetType().GUID.ToString());
        if (mutex.WaitOne(TimeSpan.Zero, true))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Single Intance");
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new MainForm());
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Ya existe otra instancia ejecutándose");
        }  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Seria algo así:

```cs
Process[] InstanciasCorriendo = Process.GetProcessByName("Notepad");

foreach(Process proc in InstanciasCorriendo){

    MessageBox.Show(proc.ProcessName);

}
```

en el caso encuentres el nombre de tu ejecutable, cierras la aplicación.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer esto que creo que es más corto ahora estoy apurado sino te daba una mejor solución, lee mañana mis comentarios

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Si entre los procesos que estan ejecutandose hay alguno que tenga mi mismo nombre entonces cierro esta instancia.
        if (Process.GetProcessesByName("Autocierre").Length > 1)
            Close();
    }


//El ejemplo completo que prometí
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        //Función importada de la librería user32.dll para mostrar una ventana en diferentes estados
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern long ShowWindow(IntPtr hwnd, uint nCmdShow);

        //Función para pasar a primer plano una ventana y activarla
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hwnd);

        //Variable que indica que hay mas de una instancia de la app ejecutandoce
        private bool prev_instances = false;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Si hay mas de una instancia de mi aplicación
            if(Process.GetProcessesByName("WindowsFormsApplication2").Length > 1)
            {
                //Asigno verdadero a la variable
                prev_instances = true;
                //Cierro el formulario
                Close();
            }
        }

        //Cuando se esta cerrando el formulario...
        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            //Si habían mas de una instancia
            if (prev_instances)
            {
                //Obtengo el proceso principal de la primera instancia de mi app
                Process p = Process.GetProcessesByName("WindowsFormsApplication2").Where(it => it.Id != Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id).First();
                //Muestro la ventana
                ShowWindow(p.MainWindowHandle, 1);
                //La activo y la paso a primer plano
                SetForegroundWindow(p.MainWindowHandle);
            }            
        }
    }
```

Espero que te sirva.